# OS X Software to remove Audio from Video

Tags: macos, video, software-rec, audio

I need to remove the audio track from a video file (it is a .mov file).

Which is the best free software to do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) - free and opensource - load your video, select both Audio and Video to "Copy", then go to Audio in main menu (on the top), and select "none" for audio track. Then save your video using new name.

PS: Avidemux sometimes does not add extension to the video, so you have to do it manually

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Garage Band or Quick Time Pro. In Garage Band you just have to drag and drop the file and delete the video section. In Quick Time, go to movie properties and select "Extract Audio".